# Why are my different language resx files being ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have been [following this page](http://www.ryadel.com/en/setup-a-multi-language-website-using-asp-net-mvc/) to make my site support multiple cultures.

the code all compiles and runs, but it seems to be ignoring my culture specific resx files.

Right now the test is pretty superficial, and I simply have 2 resource files;
`Resources.resx` and `Resources.au.resx`

My template is calling `@Resources.PageFooter` which is the only string defined in both files.

If I browse to http://mysite/index and inspect the page footer it contains my default value. If I change my url to http://mysite/au/index then it still displays the default value. However inspecting CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture and CurrentThread.CurrentCulture shows that both are now set to au, but it is still picking up and using Resources.resx not Resources.au.resx

My Resource files are in a separate folder Resources, as the article suggests.

So I am stuck.

After some investigation, I have found that if I create another resx file (for Italian), then that works.

So it looks like the files that are being ignored are the 'variations' such as American English, Australian English and so on.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: The code is pretty much boilerplate from the article. However I have just updated my question :-)

Comment: Shouldn't Australian English by `en-AU` rather than `au`?

Comment: Bingo. It had to be something silly, my Australian resx was au.resx not en-au.resx
Pebkac error, thanks both for helping me figure it out

Comment: @Matt Good job buddy. Have a great day.

Comment: For the integrity of this site, I've edited my answer to include the solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, please change `au` to `en-AU`, since this is the correct colture code for Australian English.

In your `Global.asax` file, set the `Application_BeginRequest` method like below:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string langCode = "en";  //default

     if (somecondition)
          langCode = "en-AU";

     System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(langCode);
     System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(langCode);
}
```

You need the `somecondition` I mentioned above to check where the user is coming from - by header, cookie, URI or any other way you want.

Comment: If you look at the article I followed, I am doing all you suggest (thought I am using filters and Activators, rather than BeginRequest.)